# How to use pip freeze >> requirement.txt properly with multiple environments

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I would like to understand how to use `pip` with multiple environments, I have generic flask web project where my production environment needs to pip install

```
pip install flask psycop2 Flask-SQLAlchemy
```

My dev&test environment needs these and some extra stuff

```
pip install flask psycop2 Flask-SQLAlchemy factory-boy flake8 WebTest
```

I know I could run `pip freeze >> requirements/dev.txt` then make file called `prod.txt` on the same folder cut and copy all common requirements in it and added `-r prod.txt` to my `dev.txt` for it to install prod requirements as well.

My question is, is how to pip freeze package to specific requirement.txt file while installing it let's say next I need `flake8-debugger` this will clearly need to go to dev.txt so how to make it happen without constant freezing to a single file and package copy pasting?

Should I just go and add `flake8-debugger` without a version to `dev.txt` and run `pip install -r requirements/dev.txt` or is a there more elegant workflow for this?

Comment: I'm also searching for an elegant workflow for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that this will never be fixed on requirements.txt system but the answer is here.

https://github.com/pypa/pipfile

With new Pipfile we can soon managed requirements similarily to ruby Gemfile or npm package.json

Pipfile

**Warning: this project is under active development.**

A Pipfile is a new (and much better!) way to declare dependencies for your Python environment (e.g. deployment of a web application). It will be a full replacement for the well-pervasive requirements.txt files, currently installable with $ pip install -r.

This is a concept project that will eventually be built into pip itself, once the API (including the form of a Pipfile itself) has been built out and finalized.

Remember, the important part here is Pipfile.lock. It allows deterministic builds. Today's requirements.txt can do this, and should, but often doesn't, when version specifiers aren't provided. This efforts will provide a much more pleasant user experience.

The Concept

A Pipfile will be superior to a requirements.txt file in a number of ways:

Expressive Python syntax for declaring all types of Python dependencies.
Grouping of sub-dependency groups (e.g. a testing group).
Use of a single file only will be extremely encouraged.
Pipfile.lock
Example Pipfile

Note: There will be a default source, and context manager can also be used.

```
source('https://pypi.org/', verify_ssl=True)

package('requests')
package('Django', '==1.6')
package('pinax', git='git://github.com/pinax/pinax.git', ref='1.4', editable=True)
dev_package('nose')
```